# how to expand the circle size and bar size using coord_polar with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the next cod to be used with mtcars data frame

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

plot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = rownames(mtcars) )) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = MyPaletteAll) +
    geom_bar(width = 1, size=0.5, colour="white") + ylim(c(-25, 32)) + 
    coord_polar(theta = "x") + theme_bw() + 
    theme( legend.position="bottom",
           plot.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
           panel.border = element_blank(),
           panel.grid = element_blank(),
           panel.spacing = element_blank() ) + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=3))
```

this is the result, so I wat to expand the plot in the direction of the arrows, well in all directions, I think is more space to be used !!!!
[image]

and then could increase this size/thickness of each bars !!!
[image]

Comment: I think you just need to increase the size of the plotting window - in particular, the vertical size.

Comment: If you want thicker lines in the same space, you may need to also "shrink the donut hole" by using something like `ylim(c(-5, 32))`

Comment: it did not worked using the just ylim(c(-5, 32)); I think /i have to modifies something else !!!... Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it seems that the issue is the export size rather than the code itself. You can reduce the middle hole in the plot as mentionned by @Jon to gain some space and then you can plays with the size.

For example this is a 500x500 export:
[image]

And this is a 2000x200 export:
[image]

#### Code

---

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = rownames(mtcars) )) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = sample(pals::tableau20(), 32, replace = TRUE)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, size=0.5, colour="white") + 
  ylim(c(-5, 32)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x")+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme( legend.position="bottom",
         plot.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.grid = element_blank(),
         panel.spacing = element_blank() ) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=3))
```

#### Variable size

---

What you can also do is have the size correlated to a variable, the example below show the same plot with the size based on the `mpg` from highest to smallest going inward:

[image]

Here is the code for the plot above :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

mtcars %>% 
  arrange(desc(mpg)) %>% 
  mutate(names = factor(rownames(.), levels = paste(rownames(.)))) %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x = factor(1), fill = names )) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=mpg),width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = sample(pals::tableau20(), 32, replace = TRUE)) +
  ylim(c(-200, sum(mtcars$mpg)+3)) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "x") + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
         plot.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.grid = element_blank(),
         panel.spacing = element_blank())+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=7))
```

> Note that the legend is split on 7 rows to gain some room for the export.